# Google Analytics multiple domains one website

Tags: redirect, dns, analytics

I am running a website, which you can get to by accessing any of 3 domains:

```
www.abc.com
www.asd.com
www.xyz.com
```

Will all redirect you to www.abc.com

How can I track, from which website do people access www.abc.com in Google Analytics?

Answer (score 0):

Answering for the sake of those who will come here with the same question. Here is a nice solution:
http://lanevance.com/web/web-development/tracking-301-redirects-with-google-analytics/

**Summary**

At the root folder of your website, add a .htaccess file :

```
#redirect with a 301
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/?utm_source=redirects&utm_medium=%{HTTP_HOST}&utm_content=301_redirects [L,R=301]
```

That is, redirect to www.example.com everything that is not already www.example.com (including example.com without the www), and add the current host as a GET parameter.

This will appear in the Source/Medium page of your Analytics campaigns. You can use anything you want as utm_source and utm_content.