# Google Analytics.js > track data in a website reachable by multiple domains

Tags: google-analytics, multiple-domains

I can't find this answer in the official documentation.

I'm tracking google analytics data on mycustomerwebsite.com
But the website is also working and reachable in seofriendlydomain.com

Website is the same, so I include analytics.js data in both of them.

My customer asks, to know how much traffic comes from each domain,
not needing complete data but only few stuff like % of incoming visitors or number.

I found similar topics:
[Google Analytics multiple domains one website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085350/google-analytics-multiple-domains-one-website)

Why there is no answer ? is there no solution ?

Comment: Probably because reporting questions are usually considered off-topic. Create Segments with conditions "hostname equals mycustomerwebsite.com" and "hostname equals seofriendlydomain.com" to see the numbers per domain, and better yet retire one of the domains and redirect to the other to avoid duplicate content.

Comment: What are the issues with duplicate content ?
Because to have the same website on more domains was a specific request of the customer ...

Comment: A possible SEO penalty by Google (i.e. lower rankings). I think you can mitigate this by setting one of the domains as authoritative in the webmaster tools, but this negates the (largely fictitious in any case) advantages of having two domains.

Comment: How exactly to set as authoritative a domain in Webmaster Tools ?
Because I always enter only the main domain in Webmaster Tools, not 2. Is this enough ?

Comment: Comments are not really for discussions - would you mind asking this at webmasters.stackchange.com, then I'll answer it over there (or google for "search console preferred domain", as the "preferred domain" is actually the correct term).